# How to get specific type of individuals in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I am new to SPARQL. I am creating a movie ontology in which actors and actress names are given as individuals with the object property `Acted_In`. When I write a query to get the names of actress, i get all actors and actress names. How can i specify the type to actress to see only actress names. Here is my query

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX Film: <http://www.semanticweb.org/nayye/ontologies/2019/10/untitled-ontology-4#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>


SELECT ?Actress ?Movie WHERE
{
?Actress Film:Acted_In ?Movie.
}
```

Also how can i see the datatype properties, e.g., year for these movies?

[image: Classes]

The result is as follows:
[image: ]]

Comment: without knowing the ontology, impossible to answer. Do you have a separate class for actress and actor? Or how did you model the gender?

Comment: @AKSW yes I have separate classes for Actor and Actress

Comment: then you can just add another triple pattern to your SPARQL query: `SELECT ?Actress ?Movie WHERE
{?Actress rdf:type Film:Actress .
?Actress Film:Acted_In ?Movie .
}` - SPARQL is all about pattern matching. Add more triple patterns to restrict your pattern or get additional data. For year indeed just add a triple pattern to the `?Movie` variable.

Comment: @AKSW thank you so much. I was having a hard time in the understanding of SPARQL. Now it is getting easier..

Comment: @AKSW just another question. can i get all movies ontology or atleast some movies ontologies on the internet?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "movies ontology". Can you clarify? If you mean existing RDF/OWL data about movies, Wikidata or DBpedia (Live) are the way to go